# How to read from Firebase after date child?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I upload to Firebase like this:

```
 //Get date and time
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        let dateAndTime = ("\(day)-\(month)-\(year) at: \(hour):\(minute):\(second)")    

 let userData = ["CreatedOn" : timeStamp, "Order" : dataArray] as [String : Any]
        self.ref?.child("users").child(user).child("Orders").child(dateAndTime).updateChildValues(userData, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                return
            }
        })
```

How can I read what's after `.child(dateAndTime)`? This child differentiate every time the users upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "DataSnapshot". Any time you read Database data, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot.